# How to implement an unbeatable version of Tic-Tac-Toe game without involving Machine learning algorithms?

Tags: python-3.x

I have successfully implemented the single player game. But I am unable to figure out on how to implement the unbeatable version.

Answer (score 0):

The simple algorithm for unbeatable tic tac toe has been described in many places, e.g. [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Win-at-Tic-Tac-Toe). Implement it and off you go :-)